# Trying to get "git clone" to work behind a strict firewall? Help me ask net admin for what I need

Tags: firewall, git

ULTIMATE GOAL, to get this command to work:

```
git clone https://github.com/ablab/quast.git
```

Net admin says these are open:

> Note the destination IP's are:
>
> ```
> host1.github.com  192.30.253.112
> host2.github.com  192.30.253.113
> security1.ubuntu.com  91.189.91.26
> security2.ubuntu.com  91.189.91.23
> security3.ubuntu.com  91.189.88.149
> security4.ubuntu.com  91.189.88.152
> security5.ubuntu.com  91.189.88.162
> security6.ubuntu.com  91.189.88.161
> ```
>
> Also note the Services being allowed are:
>
> ```
> NAME      PORT
> --------------    ---------
> l_tcp_9418    9418
> service-http  80
> ssh           22
> ```

Troubleshooting I've already done.  Ping works great, wget google.com doesn't work as I haven't explicitly opened it.  I've tried to open connections to github but clearly I'm missing something otherwise "git clone" would work.  Any help?

```
=======================================
TESTING ping google.com
=======================================
PING google.com (172.217.6.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord37s03-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.6.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=8.05 ms
64 bytes from ord37s03-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.6.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=8.00 ms
64 bytes from ord37s03-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.6.110): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=8.02 ms



#=======================================
# TESTING ping github.com
#=======================================
PING github.com (192.30.253.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.30.253.113: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=29.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.253.113: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=30.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.253.113: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=30.0 ms



#=======================================
# TESTING wget google.com
#=======================================
--2017-07-11 07:13:14--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.6.110, 2607:f8b0:4009:812::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.6.110|:80...


#=======================================
# TESTING wget https://github.com/ablab/quast/archive/master.zip
#=======================================
--2017-07-11 07:13:24--  https://github.com/ablab/quast/archive/master.zip
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.113, 192.30.253.112
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.113|:443...


#=======================================
# TESTING wget --verbose https://github.com/ablab/quast/archive/master.zip
#=======================================
--2017-07-11 07:13:34--  https://github.com/ablab/quast/archive/master.zip
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.112|:443...


#=======================================
# TESTING git clone https://github.com/ablab/quast.git
#=======================================
Cloning into 'quast'...



#=======================================
# TESTING git clone -v https://github.com/ablab/quast.git
#=======================================
Cloning into 'quast'...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clone using git over HTTPS, you need the HTTPS port open, which is 443. But, since you have SSH allowed, you can use git over SSH:

```
git clone git@github.com:ablab/quast.git
```

For this, you'll need to create a Github account and [add an SSH private key](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

You can also use the plain git protocol (which uses port 9418 by default):

```
git clone git://github.com/ablab/quast.git
```